# Regex Match till first occurrence of string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match starting from `@Path("/v11/data")` till next `@GET`.

This is a file and I'm using this expression `\/v11\/data(\s?.*)+` but this turns greedy and doesn't stop at the first match of @GET.

When I use this expression `\/v11\/data(\s?.*)+\@GET`. Please help

DEMO LINK: https://regex101.com/r/BDsUvM/3

```
public class TestResource {
private final TestResource testResource;

public TestResource(TestResource testResource) {
    this.testResource = testResource;
}

@GET
@Path("/v11/data")
@Resource[enter(asdf)
public void getTest(@PathParam("asdf") @asdf String asdf,
                           @PathParam("dfg") dgf dgf,
                           @NotNull @SS ss sess) {

    testResource.getTest();
}

@GET
@Path("/v45/data")
public void getData(@PathParam("asdf") @asdf String asdf,
                           @PathParam("ewr") erw ewr,
                           @NotNull @ss ss ss) {

    testResource.getData();
}

@GET
@Path("/v45/data")
public void getData(@PathParam("asdf") @asdf String asdf,
                           @PathParam("ewr") erw ewr,
                           @NotNull @ss ss ss) {

    testResource.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match starting from @Path and match all the next lines that do not start with @GET using a negative lookahead in a repeating group.

```
@Path\("\/v11\/data.*(?:\r?\n(?!@GET).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH8NvM/1)

If @GET should be there, you could use a capturing group

```
@Path\("\/v11\/data.*((?:\r?\n(?!@GET).*)*)\r?\n\s*@GET
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJ7bso/1)

**Edit**

Or a shorter more readable version as suggested by [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)

```
Path\("/v11/data"\)\s+((?:.*\R)+?)@GET
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YpbVn7/1)

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for your suggestion, I have added it as well. Always happy to get your advice :-)